# Long Response Time spent on "ObserveChanges" | Meteor js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, meteor

I'm load testing a basic chat room app and am noticing in Kadira that about 286ms are spent on "ObserveChanges" on a subscription.

[image: Kadira]

The 'roomDetail' subscription uses a roomId param to find all "Message" documents with matching roomId and looks like this:

```
Meteor.publish('roomDetail', function(roomId) {
    return Messages.find({roomId: roomId}, {limit: 100, sort: { submitted : -1 }});
});
```

I'm wondering how I can reduce the response time on "observeChanges" here. I've already added an index on the "Messages" collection:

Messages = new Mongo.Collection('messages');

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
    // Index on roomid and reverse date order
    Messages._ensureIndex({roomId: 1, submitted: -1});
}
```

But I don't think that will help me with the high response time on "observeChanges".

**Any ideas on how I can best reduce this response time? Am I not following certain best practices here?**

Comment: It's hard to say just with this information. You mentioned you were load testing - do you get the same response time when the server isn't under load? What does your CPU usage look like? Are the database and your server in the same data center?

Comment: Actual time spent on DB is 30ms(see initialPollingTime). Sometime when CPU usage increases, something like this could happen. I haven't tackle it down.
Again, try to see your average response time during the load test. This might be some outlier.

Comment: @ArunodaSusiripala I have a similar issue but my initialPollingTime is really large... 711ms... is improving indexing the general way to solve this or are their other methods too? I guess in general I am interested know what how you look at a trace like this and traces in general and determine what is important, what could indicate a problem, and potential mitigations for those issues.

Comment: Having the same issue now on my production app.  Any solutions found for this?

Answer (score 0):

I think a MongoDB index on `roomId` would help. There is no official way to automatically do this from within an app, but you could a) just do it from the Mongo console, or b) I seem to remember that there is some way to get to the standard Node MongoDB driver from a Meteor collection, with which you could create the index.